# How to move the tab panels from above the control panel to the main panel

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a very long shiny syntax in which the tab panels are located right above the control panel. I was wondering to know how can I move the tabs to the main panel (as shown in the below image). I know that one solution could be to define the tab panels inside the main panel but for some reason, I would like to avoid this. Thanks.
Nader

**Actual problem**

[image]

**sample code (the problem)**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Tabsets"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Plot"), 
    tabPanel("Summary"), 
    tabPanel("Table")),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput('sampleSize', 'Sample Size', 
                  min=1, max=nrow(dataset), value=min(1000, nrow(dataset)), 
                  step=500, round=0)
    ),

    mainPanel(

      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**sample code (possible solution)**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Tabsets"),



  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput('sampleSize', 'Sample Size', 
                  min=1, max=nrow(dataset), value=min(1000, nrow(dataset)), 
                  step=500, round=0)
    ),

    mainPanel(

      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Plot"), 
        tabPanel("Summary"), 
        tabPanel("Table"))

      )
    )
  )




server <- function(input, output) {
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, specifying the tabs in the the mainPanel as you've done in your possible solution is the only way to put the tabs in the mainPanel. Why do you want to avoid this? Is there some other behaviour you're looking for?

Comment: I have a different control panel for each tab and that is why I did not define the tabs in the mainPanel. For example, the control panel under the "plot" tab is different than "the interactive map" tab. I know that I could put the tabs in the mainPanel while still having different control panels. Is there any way to fix this without making a huge change in the syntax?